# Bootstrap - table-striped starting on opposite color

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, html-table

My striped bootstrap table starts with the gray color after the heading in each case.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered text-nowrap display-23">
   <thead class="fw-bold bg-gray">
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">Title 1</th>
         <th scope="col">Title 2</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>One</td>
         <td>Two</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Three</td>
         <td>Four</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

[Codeply Example](https://www.codeply.com/p/QTSV7Cai02)

I want to reverse the order of the colors so that the first row color after the heading is white, instead of gray. Does anyone know the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply insert a blank hidden tr in the body:

```
      <tbody>
           <tr style="display:none">
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>One</td>
             <td>Two</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Three</td>
             <td>Four</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `table-striped` class and add `class="active"` in `<tr>` where ever you want the gray color.

```
<table class="table table-bordered text-nowrap display-23">
   <thead class="fw-bold bg-gray">
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">Title 1</th>
         <th scope="col">Title 2</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>One</td>
         <td>Two</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-active">
         <td>Three</td>
         <td>Four</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @develop7761 If you got the answer. Please give it a tick ✔. It would me much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css file:

```
    .table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(2n+1)>td,
    .table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(2n+1)>th {
            background-color: white;
    }

    .table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(n+2)>td,
    .table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(n+2)>th {
            background-color: grey;
    }
```